Notifications have stopped working on iOS - react native
All of a sudden notifications have stopped working on iOS. the logs on the Xcode console are showing two warning:
2024-12-31 19:23:31.439656+0500 trivialapp[31127:217995] 10.3.0 - [FirebaseCore][I-COR000008] The project's Bundle ID is inconsistent with either the Bundle ID in 'GoogleService-Info.plist', or the Bundle ID in the options if you are using a customized options. To ensure that everything can be configured correctly, you may need to make the Bundle IDs consistent. To continue with this plist file, you may change your app's bundle identifier to 'com.aparna.seventeendegreesnorth'. Or you can download a new configuration file that matches your bundle identifier from https://console.firebase.google.com/ and replace the current one.
2024-12-31 19:23:31.493485+0500 trivialapp[31127:217995] 10.3.0 - [GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler][I-SWZ001011] App Delegate Proxy is disabled.
2024-12-31 19:23:31.545162+0500 trivialapp[31127:217995] 10.3.0 - [FirebaseMessaging][I-FCM002022] APNS device token not set before retrieving FCM Token for Sender ID '899629753079'. Notifications to this FCM Token will not be delivered over APNS.Be sure to re-retrieve the FCM token once the APNS device token is set.
I have double-checked my bundle ID in Firebase, Apple Developer account and Xcode, the bundleID is same as GoogleService-Info.plist. Also regarding the second warning I have completed all the steps to setup notifications for iOS mentioned in the docs here https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage/ios-setup
But still no luck! Any help is greatly appreciated.
